# Snap joystick value to minimum magnitude when it falls below

Tags: mathematics, joystick

I got a joystick displayed in the image below with range -1 to 1.
Green area is 80% of the total circle and yellow area is 20%.

I want to get corrected values for both areas. For example:

1. If given point falls under yellow range I want to get actual input value.
2. if given point is within green area how can I get maximum value in green area ie. 80% at same direction.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is some pretty trivial linear algebra.

```
Vector2 SnapToMinimumLength(Vector2 input, float minimum) {
    // Most vector libraries will give you a method to do this,
    // but in case you're not using one and aren't familiar with
    // vector magnitude/normalization, I'll show all the steps.
    float squaredLength = input.x*input.x + input.y*input.y;

    if (squaredLength > 0 && squaredLength < minimum * minimum) {
        float scale = minimum / Mathf.Sqrt(squaredLength);
        input.x *= scale;
        input.y *= scale;
    }
    return input;
}
```

To snap to the outer edge of the green area at 80% of the circle radius, you'd use:

```
Vector2 snappedInput = SnapToMinimumLength(rawInput, 0.8);
```

The one exception here is when the input is (0, 0). Then it *has* no direction, so this code skips trying to snap it anywhere and returns the input unchanged. You could decide to force a direction arbitrarily (like saying `(0, 0)->(0, 0.8)`) or cache the last non-zero direction and keep using that, or fall back on some different behaviour appropriate to your application.

Comment: Worked perfectly ... thank you so much.